# Run the scheduler after Thread.sleep

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

My code stores the transactions for each 60 sec in a List and then the list is cleaned using Scheduler:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync

@Slf4j
public class ApplicationConfig {


    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60 * 1000, initialDelay = 60 * 1000)
    public void scheduleTransactionClearance() {

        log.info("Performing the clearance the transactions in each 60 sec from the storage");
        TransactionCollectors.getTransactionList().clear();
    }

}
```

An integration test use `Thread.sleep(5000)` so then I try to get the statistics, I have the transactions for 1 min and 5 sec. I correct the code to manually check and delete if any transactions are older than 60 sec:

```
private void deleteOlderTransaction(List<Transaction> transactions) {

        final int initialTransactionsSize = transactions.size();

        final boolean isOlderTransactionsDeleted = transactions.removeIf(tx -> Duration.between(tx.getLocalDateTime(), LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)).toSeconds() >= 60);

        if (isOlderTransactionsDeleted) {

            log.info("we have deleted translations that are older than 60 seconds and the deleted transactions count =" + (initialTransactionsSize - transactions.size()));
        }
    }
```

However, this situation may arrive only once and I don't need to make this call for each time which is unnecessary and code looks bad as well.

Is there any way to know if the `Thread.sleep` is called and based on that condition we can run the scheduler?

Also is there any way I can check from a method that the current thread is just awake from sleep and if true, I will try to delete the older transactions if any?

Comment: Don't... use a proper caching framework which does all this for you, you are basically trying to write your own caching solution, which might look simply but it really isn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum This is very helpful as can be done with  `CacheEvict`

Comment: You don't need `CacheEvict`. You just need to configure your caching to hold elements for 60 seconds. The caching will handle everything else, transparently.

Comment: This is answer the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059670/spring-boot-evicting-cache-with-dynamic-ttl-period

and 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable