# How to let Spring Boot evict single entries in cache after a certain TimeToLive (TTL)

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, evict

## Update (tl;dr)

- Single entries shall be evicted from Cache after their TTL is due.
- Setup:

  - **Java:** 17
  - **spring-boot.version:** 3.0.x

---

## Objective

Requests providing an ID (each) are asking for data.
The data is stored in a repository - we can assume any kind of a KV-Store alike <fooId, fooData>.
To speed up the repositorie's answer, the repository is wrapped by a SpringBoot-Cache.

**Approach** for fast answers:

1. **Ask the cache** first
2. **Ask the Repository**, if the cache could not provide an answer.

For the cache to stay small the entries shall be evicted.

Samples and guides like ( https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial ) hand suitable code for eviction ...

... **BUT the entries in the Cache shall not be evicted alltogether.**
Each entry shall exist in the Cache for (e.g.) 30 minutes after the last request.

### Sample event flow:

To say it using events:

**a) Entry *foo1* is requested**

- *foo1* will be evicted in 30 minutes from now (-> 30)

.. 10 minuts pass (Sum: 10 min)

**b) Entry *foo2* is requested**

- *foo2* will be evicted in 30 minutes from now (-> 40)

.. 10 minuts pass (Sum: 20 min)

**c) Entry *foo1* is requested (again)**

- *foo1* is reset to be evicted in 30 minutes from now (-> 50)

.. 10 minuts pass (Sum: 30 min)

- *nothing happens*

  - *foo1* has 20 Minutes remaining until TTL is due
  - *foo2* has 20 Minutes remaining until TTL is due

.. 10 minuts pass (Sum: 40 min)

**d) Entry *foo2* is evicted as TTL is expired**

- *foo1* has 10 Minutes remaining until TTL is due

.. 10 minuts pass (Sum: 50 min)

**e) Entry *foo1* is evicted as TTL is expired**

## Is there an easy way to solve this issue without using external libraries/products?

Sample external libraries/products not to use:

- EhCache
- Gemfire
- Guava

---

Thanks for any advice   :)

Comment: Spring provides only "simple cache" and "no cache", if you don't want to use 3rd party and don't want to implement custom - you are in a dilemma! :) (for most-all 3rd party providers TTL/TTI is a "standard feature")

Answer (score 0):

## Research approaches ... .. .

#### (i) Is there an Implementation from SpringBoot itself?

From ..

- [Spring boot - Evicting Cache with dynamic TTL period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059670/spring-boot-evicting-cache-with-dynamic-ttl-period))

.. I could extract as of 2020:

```
If you are using Spring's default implementation you won't be able to set Cache TTL.
But with other providers such as EhCache, Gemfire & Guava you can do that but
only during configuring Cache Managers.
```

--> **Sadly: NOT to the recent knowledge ... :-/**

---

#### (ii) Evict everything

Of couse this is not desirable in the first place, but the cache could be evicted completely to be refilled

###### Downside:

- NOT the desired option, to much loss
- Harsh tradeoff between a large cache with many dead entries and deleting many needed entries from cache

  - Maybe the time to evict due to a huge cache is exactly a timeslot of heavy usage.

---

#### (iii) Wrap the Cache

If the entries in the Cache are 'big'/'huge', a reasonable approach would be to setup another *hashmap* **fooTTL**, which stores **<ID, TTL>**-pairs.

Then a **fixed delayed/scheduled** function loops the **fooTTL** and evicts due entries from the cache.

###### Downside:

- Cumbersome and not less applicable for small <Key, Value> pairs within the main cache.

---

#### (iv) Reevaluate the use of external libraries/products

Maybe the as the use of **external libraries/products** offers a better set of functions or a less cumbersome implementation.

###### Downside:

- NOT in the initial scope.

---

#### (v) Replace the Cache

In the first place the `SpringBoot Simple Cache` is a "Key-Value"-Pair HashMap<K,V>.
Maybe it is even a ConcurentHashMap<K,V>.

Anyways, a handcrafted **class using a ConcurentHashMap<K,V>** might be your solution, as everything stays *in memory*.

The functions from the `SpringBoot Simple Cache` are pretty simple.

```
- add(K,V)
- update(K,V)
- get(K)     -->  V
- exist(K)   -->  Bool
- evict(K)
```

This interface could be extended by:

```
- deleteByTtl
```

The key stays equivalent to the implementation given by Spring.
Additionally the new value field wrappes two fields:

- the *value* used previously for the `SpringBoot Simple Cache`
- a ttl timestamp

Finally the `deleteByTtl`-funtion can be `@Sceduled` to iterate over all entries evicting only those with an expired ttl.

###### Downside:

- Does not use the SpringBoot-@Cachable notation.

Still approach **(v)** remains straight foreward regarding the persued functionality.